# AES-CBC then SHA vs AES-GCM for encrypting and authenticating a web token

Tags: aes, cbc, sha-256, gcm, jwt

I am trying to have something like JWT but kinda ad hoc and encrypted. The token itself is simply a stringified JSON that contains the user ID and Unix timestamp.

Now, I tried to use AES-128-GCM, however I did some simple modification in the ciphertext before decrypting, just appended some bytes to the ciphertext, and found that it decrypts successfully, does that mean that those bytes were counted as padding and that AES GCM is authenticate then encrypt algorithm?

I feel that encrypt-then-authenticate feels more secure to me. Also, is AES GCM authentication even secure enough to be compared to SHA256 for example or is it CRC tier for quick integrity and cannot be used for secure authentication like HMAC?

In other words: is AES-128-CBC then SHA-256 more secure than AES-128-GCM?

Comment: What is the delegation structure? Do you have a single server minting and verifying credentials? Can users delegate their credentials to other users? Can users add additional caveats? If all of these are yes, you would be better off using [Macaroons](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub41892.html).

Comment: Thanks, I heard of Macaroons but I think it's too complex for my use case, I just want a token that contains the user id so that it can be verified in my own server. I could just use JWT but I wanted to create an ad hoc alternative that is simple just the json containing the user id and timestamp, encrypted and authenticated

Comment: Macaroons are as simple as it gets. No need to encrypt. $(0, \operatorname{HMAC}_\text{server-secret}(0 \| 0))$ as the (UID=0) user's credential and $(0, \text{msg}, \operatorname{HMAC}_\text{previous-tag}(1 \| \text{msg}))$ as the authenticated invocation over the message $\text{msg}$. If you don't need any provisioning caveats, don't implement them. But if you later want them. They are trivial to add. Your "unix timestamp" looks like a caveat to expire after some time and may be better encoded as TAI64. If you want to encrypt anything, you've conveniently got a preshared key already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just appended some bytes to the ciphertext, and found that it decrypts
>   successfully

Normally this shouldn't happen, as the appended bytes surely aren't a valid authentication tag for the previous "ciphertext". I suppose (but don't know!) the implementation you are using encoded the length of the ciphertext, the associated data and the tag and retrieved these values upon decryption, ignoring the added values, yielding a correct decryption.

> AES GCM is authenticate then encrypt algorithm? because I feel that
>   encrypt then authenticate feels more secure to me

AES-GCM is an *authenticated encryption algorithm*. Encrypt-then-Authenticate is one specific construction that achieves this general definition and is [indeed preferable to Authenticate-then-Encrypt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26638/23623), which is why GCM *internally* does encrypt-then-authenticate and so AES-GCM achieves the same security definition as CBC-then-HMAC.

> is AES-128-CBC then SHA-256 more secure than AES-128-GCM?

When you say "AES-128-CBC then SHA-256" I suppose you actually mean AES-128-CBC with HMAC-SHA256 authentication on the ciphertext.

Then yes, *technically* that is more secure, because HMAC-SHA256 requires $2^{128}$ operations to come up with a forgery, whereas AES-128-GCM allows you to perform a multi-target search for a key that works dropping security slightly below $2^{128}$. So it also has a serious security level unlike CRC. Also from this we can infer that both are secure, as neither $2^{128}$ nor $2^{100}$ operations are feasible making them both "secure" (a.k.a. "meh, can't break"), so you might as well use the easier-to-use and faster AES-GCM, assuming you have hardware support available, which is the case on modern x86 processors.

See Squeamish's comments below for a more detailed discussion of the actual values. Also see their answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67367/23623).

Comment: The authentication tags for GCM are typically shorter (80 or 96 bits) and not as equally distributed so a HMAC (even truncated) does add quite some additional confidence (which is especially important for tokens where forgery is a threat). However 12byte Tags might still be acceptable if compactness is required.

Comment: Isn't GHASH provides $\sqrt{n}$-bit protection againts forgery ?

Comment: @kelalaka indeed $2^{n/2}$ online queries are sufficient to break GCM authenticity (the attacker advantage scales quadratically with the number of total queries and plaintext length). I'm currently unsure whether this implies 64-bit security for GCM in general.

Comment: Ok, Whoever gets it first, note it here :)

Comment: @kelalaka so I wrote up a question and while writing the answer for this case came to my mind: In this case the security is probably $2^{128}$, assuming the server re-keys / re-issues on encountering an invalid tag. I asked anyways, because I'm still not 100% sure / confused.

Comment: Rekeying limits the quadratic term in the forgery probability—which is why NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 effectively rekeys for every message—but rekeying doesn't reset the forgery probability back to zero!  You need to make sure that for the _entire volume of data_ your application can _ever_ process, assuming the adversary saturates your bandwidth with forgeries, the probability of a _single_ forgery is negligible.

Comment: P.S.  The forgery probability for HMAC-SHA256 after ‘only’ $2^{128}$ messages sent is quite high.  But also, AES-128-GCM admits _offline_ attacks that reduce the cost of recovering one of $n$ keys to $2^{128}/n$ AES computations, which for a million users could drop below $2^{100}$, whereas for HMAC-SHA256 with a 256-bit key it is $2^{256}/n$ HMAC-SHA256 computations which is unimaginable for any imaginable number of users.

Comment: Addendum: AES-GMAC requires a 96-bit nonce, too small to be chosen randomly for large applications. HMAC-SHA256 does not require a nonce, and can safely be truncated to a 128-bit tag without reducing the forgery probability bound below what you would have gotten with AES-GMAC.  (Of course, if you're encrypting too you need a nonce or IV overhead anyway.)  Clarification to the postscript: What I mean to say is you should use AES-256, not AES-128.